# How to keep alive a JSONArray for widgets?

Tags: java, android, widget

My app has a widget with two buttons that goes back and forth and displays information stored in a JSONArray. It works very well but the problem is when i close the app the widget stops working because the JSONArray becomes null. How can i keep it working even when the app is closed ?

its too long to post it here but this is the part when i click next button

```
if(intent.getAction().equals(NEXT_LISTING)){
        try{
            if (listingNumber !=15)
            {
                listingNumber++;
            }

            JSONObject latestListing = jsonListings.getJSONObject(listingNumber);
            String titleString = latestListing.getString("title");
            String descriptionString = latestListing.getString("description");
            String categoryString = latestListing.getString("category");
            Date postDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").parse(latestListing.getString("created"));
            Date newDate = new Date(postDate.getTime() + Utils.getCurrentTimezoneOffset() * (3600 * 100));
            String createdDate = Utils.getFormattedDate(newDate);

            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.njoftime_widget);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.title, titleString);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.description, descriptionString);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.textView_category, categoryString);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.textView_date, createdDate);

            for(int i=0; i < categoriesList.size();i++)
            {
                if(categoriesList.get(i).get(0).equals(latestListing.getString("category")))
                {
                    views.setImageViewResource(R.id.category_icon_widget, iconList.get(i));
                }
            }

            if(listingThumbnails.get(listingNumber) != null)
            {
                views.setViewVisibility(R.id.listing_photo, View.VISIBLE);
                views.setImageViewUri(R.id.listing_photo, Uri.parse(""));
                Bitmap roundedBitmap = getRoundedLeftCornerBitmap(listingThumbnails.get(listingNumber), 10);
                views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.listing_photo,roundedBitmap);
            }
            else
            {
                views.setViewVisibility(R.id.listing_photo, View.GONE);
            }
            // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget

            ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, NjoftimeWidget.class);
            AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(componentName, views);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Share your code for the widget

Comment: Where do you keep jsonListings and when do you initialize or remove that field?

Comment: When the widget is first started i make a Http Request to my web service and get my json and store it as a JSONArray. then i go back and forth locally without doing more requests.

Comment: Are you sure the jsonListings is null? I suspect that the latestListing(JSONObject) may be null for the incoming listingNumber.If you share your logcat output that'll be helpful.

Comment: no im sure, thats why i have an if condition for listingNumber. I think its because these are runtime variables and thats why they are null when i close the app